# How to switch from OneToMany to OneToOne relationship?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Suppose we have the following relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table
class EntityA {
   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Account account;
    private List<EntityB> bEntities;

}

@Entity
@Table
class EntityB {
   
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id", nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private EntityA aEntity;
}
```

then I want to downgrade from OneToMany to OneToOne relationship

```
@Entity
@Table
class EntityA {
   
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "aEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private EntityB bEntity;

}

@Entity
@Table
class EntityB {
   
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id", nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private EntityA aEntity;
}
```

My problem is that when I am trying to get EntityA I get an hibernate error with the message: "More than one row with the given identifier was found: 14085854-f126-4e61-9f3c-2c6b215d536a, for class: EntityB".
Can somebody help me to resolve this issue? Do I have to delete everything in the database in order to get rid of that error?

Comment: let's say you have an entity A with a many to one relations to B. Example A -> B1, B2, B3. Now if you want one to one then you need to go A -> B - but you have 3 B's: B1, B2, B3 - you need to fix this so that you have only 1 B entity.

Comment: how do I fix it? do I have to remove everything in the database?

Comment: you can remove B2, B3, so you will be left with only B1 or create A1, A2, A3 and re-attach them to B1, B2, B3 or remove everything and rebuild your DB.

Comment: If its a test DB, purge it, Or else, remove it manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is specifically a data issue.

The error: `"More than one row with the given identifier was found: 14085854-f126-4e61-9f3c-2c6b215d536a, for class: EntityB".` is specifically saying that there are at least 2 objects ( EntityB ) that are related to `14085854-f126-4e61-9f3c-2c6b215d536a` ( EntityA ).

To fix this you will have to fix the data first.